# firebase phone authentication doestn't send an OTP code anymore

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

i'm building an app that allows users to sign up via their phone number. in the beginning the
phone authentication feature worked well, i was able to enter my phone number and the firebase sent back the OTP code within seconds and i was to do it several times. but after that firebase started to take a longer time to send the OTP code around an hour, and now it doesn't send the OTP code anymore. i tried multiple numbers but had the same problem. so, i debugged my code and when i reach to the verifyPhoneNumber function(which is provided by firebase authentication) only the verficationfaild gets called.
here is my code:
firstly, when the user click on the sign up button the following function gets called:

```
void sendPhoneNumber() {
String phoneNumber = phoneController.text.trim();
if (country != null && phoneNumber.isNotEmpty) {
  ref
      .read(authControllerProvider)
      .signInWithPhone(context, '+${country!.phoneCode}$phoneNumber');
} else {
  showSnackBar(context: context, content: 'Fill out all the fields');
}
}
```

then, the signInWithPhone() function inside of the authcontrollerprovider gets called and here it is implementation:

```
 void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) {
authRepository.signInWithPhone(context, phoneNumber);
}
```

finally, the signINWithPhone() function which is responsible of dealing with firebase gets called and here its code:

```
void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
try {
  await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    },
    verificationFailed: (e) {
      print("no");
      throw Exception(e.message);
    },
    codeSent: ((String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        OTPScreen.routeName,
        arguments: verificationId,
      );
    }),
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
      print("doen");
    },
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  showSnackBar(context: context, content: e.message!);
}
}
```